# SOSL Filter on Community Topics

Tags: sosl, lightning-community, topics

Back in 2014 @pchittum had mentioned in the [Discussion Forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009F33IAE) that he hoped that maybe some day we might be able to filter by topics using SOSL:

> My wish is that some day in the future you can just throw a topic at
>   SOSL, and then have SOSL return a bunch of records/feeds/etc that are
>   being used by that topic...but as of today, that is just a dream.
>
> -*peter_sfdc*

My research and attempts so far (mainly from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm)) indicates that today in 2018 this is not possible.

The only way I have been able to do so is by querying (via SOQL) on a specific topicId, fetch the EntityId's by type (for example: feedItem, Knowledge, etc, etc...) and then do a query using SOSL with a 'Where' Clause that uses an inclusion filter on the EntityId's I mapped in my previosu query as follows:

SOQL:

```
SELECT Entityid, EntityType from TopicAssignment where Topicid='TopicId' 
AND EntityType='Knowledge'
```

SOSL:

```
FIND {*Keyword} RETURNING Object(Id, Title WHERE ((Id IN
 (MyRidiculouslyLongListOfIds)) AND PublishStatus='online' AND Language='en_US'))
```

Is it still not possible to filter SOSL on Topics? If not, is there a better approach than the one above as of today?